# Как работает гарантия ресурсов при виртуализации?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, виртуальная-машина, виртуализация, контейнеры

Во многих статях вижу, что в преимуществах виртуализации указывается "более честное распределение ресурсов, чем при контейнеризации". Т.е., как я понимаю, подразумевается, что технология виртуализации предоставляет гарантии выделения ресурсов более приоритетным виртуальным машинам.

1. Как это работает и как обеспечивается гарантия выделения?
2. Что мне мешает установить одинаковый ресурс по оперативной памяти в 12 GB двум виртуалкам на машине с 16 GB RAM? Как в этом случае будут
   распределены ресурсы и кому отдан приоритет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У меня есть некоторый опыт работы с обеими технологиями, и я постараюсь ответить на Ваш вопрос макисмально объективно.

На самом деле, дьявол кроектся в слове "честное". Ведь "честность" - это не такой критерий распределения ресурсов, котрый можно померить численно. Можно померить latency ответа на запрос, можно оценить, насколько "кол-во выполненных за единицу времени операций в виртуальной среде" отличается от "кол-во выполненных за единицу времени операций на хост-машине" (т. е каковы "затраты cpu на виртуализацю") и т.п.

Вторым "дьявольским словом" является слово "гарантия". Но к нему можно особо не придираться, мы интуитвно понимаем что "гарантия выделения" - это значит "ресурсы будут выделены".

Теперь - короткий ответ на Ваш вопрос.

1. Гарантия выделения работает так: если Вы имеете хостовую машину, в которой (просто для примера) 16 гб памяти и 8 ядер процессора, и Вы создадите на ней две виртуалки, каждой из котрых выдадим по 8 Гб памяти и по 4 ядра процессора, то гарантия будет обеспечена. (мы пренебрегли памятью, которая нужна хост-машине, но это не очень важно для понимания)

Фактически, в этом случае гарантия обеспечивается за счет избыточности: мы никогда, ни при каких обстоятельствах, даже если все две виртуальные машины начнут одновременно активно потреблять ресурсы - не выйдем за пределы, когда "ресурсов не хватает": кол-во выдеделнных на виртуальные машины ресурсов суммарно равно имеющимся у хоста ресурсам.

Что обеспечивает такая "избыточность"? Что все страницы памяти, котрые используются в каждой виртуалке, могут соответствовать страницам настоящей памяти, имеющейся на хосте, и не будут вытеснены в своп. То же самое - с ядрами процессора:  независимо от того, в какой момент и сколько ядер будет задействовано - всем виртуальным ядрам соответствуют физические, и не придётся одно физическое ядро делить "на всех".

Замечу, что на практике такая "честная" или "избыточная" стратегия распредеелния ресурсов встречается не очень часто. Например, мне она встречалась при аренде виртуалки для HFT "рядом с биржей" - но и ценник там был космический.

В более дешевых и массовых случаях так не делают. Обычно применяется стратегия "мы напихаем на хост побольше виртуалок, в надежде, что все они не захотят актвино работать одновременно". То есть, количество "вируальных" ресурсов, выделенных виртуалкам, обычно больше, чем физических ресурсов у хоста, иногда - в несколько раз.

Можно также заметить, что у поставщиков услуг в контрактах встречаются предупреждения мелким шрифтом о том, что "потребители ресурсов, в течение длительного времени потребляющие все выделенные ресурсы на 100%, могут быть отключены от сервиса".

Это как раз короткий ответ на Ваш вопрос номер два: Вам ничего не машает "установить одинаковый ресурс по оперативной памяти в 12 GB двум виртуалкам на машине с 16 GB RAM". Всё будет работать. До тех пор, пока на обеих виртуалках не запустится какой то процесс, который активно безает по страницам памяти и читает их (или, что еще хуже, пишет). Тогда хост - система начнёт уходить в своп.

На этом "короткий ответ", по большому счёту, закончен.

Дальше я приведу дополнительные рассуждения. Мне кажется, что особых преимуществ у систем виртуализации на основе виртуалок перед контейнерами нет. Для этого надо определиться, что я сам понимаю под словом "честное распределение ресурсов": по большому счету, я хочу добиться отсутствия "торможения", то есть низкого latency при запросах к вируалке/контейнеру.

Давайте посмотрим, из за чего всё может тормозить. Причины следуюшие:

1. память убежала в своп
2. процессорные ядра обслуживают слишком много виртуальных ядер одновременно - "тактов не хватает"
3. Кэш. Из за "перепрыгивания" исполнения процесса с одного физического ядра на другое - происходит каждый раз при "прыжке" приходитяс заново загружать кеш данными и командами, а это - долго. По крайней мере, дольше, чем если этих "прыжков" нет

С 1) и 2) бороться бесполезно так же, как с законаами физики. Если оперативной памяти не хвает на всех - она не появится из воздуха. То есть, здесь и виртуалки, и контейнеры не позволяют преодолеть физический предел по памяти и ядрам.

Но всё же некотрое преимущество контейнеров над виртуалками я здесь вижу: в от время, как между виртуалками память "подедлена на всех", у контейнеров - если их искусственно не ограничивать - есть возможность делить между всеми контейнерами всю память хоста. Если у вас нет контейнеров, котрые ведут себя не по джентельменски (и к которым за это приходит oom-killer), то, возможно, делить всю память между всеми - не такая уж плохая идея.

А вот если *надо* ограничить контейнер по памяти - нет проблем, есть такое ограничение в докере. я не вижу смысла копировать в ответ все опции, они описаны на [странице документации](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/)

То же относится к пункту 3): в виртуалках можно "прибить виртуальные ядра к реальным". В этом случае перезагрузки кеша не потребуется - кеш будет почти всё время содержать актуальные для данного VCPU данные. Но точно то же самое можно сделать и в случае контейнеров. И вообще, практически на любое свойство, которое можно настроит на виртуалке, есть соответствующая настройка у контейнера.

Поэтому, финальное замечание: понятие "более честное выделение ресурсов" имеет смысл только в определенном контексте. Вы можете добавить этот контекст, например, приведя ссылки на статьи, где Вам это встретилось, и тогда мы еще раз вернёмся к вопросу!